# How to count the number of arrays nested within a JavaScript object by name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a generic function that needs to check the number of items in the array that is named, but I don't always know what the name is going to be called.  Is there a way to do this?

array:

```
// added array example here per request:
var myArray = { "name": "myname", "data": [ "item1": [1], "item2": [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], "item3": [41,42,51,491]}

// where length is the number of objects in the array.
var mycount = someitem.getProperty("UnknownName").length;
```

what I want to do is call some function that does this:

```
var mycount = specialCountFunction(someitem, name);
```

Comment: Please show an simple example of the structure of your object, so that we can help you better.

Comment: This question is incomplete without showing us an example of the data you are searching through and a boilerplate/description of a function you want written (e.g. what info you're going to pass it and what info you want it to return).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to get the length of an array in an object?

For example, your object

```
var obj = {
    "children": [ "john", "mark", "sam" ]
}
```

Get the length with `obj["children"].length`

Or the length of an object ?

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(obj);
```

Comment: Yes.  That is precisely what I mean.  It is the same thing but its in the rows object in an ng-grid.  Each cell can have an array based on the field name and I need to count the number of arrays in the field children.

Comment: @user3250966 - Please use the "edit" button in your question to paste in an example of the actual data you're searching.

Answer (score 1):

In your `specialCountFunction()`, receive the property name as a string, and then use square brackets after `item` to evaluate the value of the string in order to use it as a property name.

```
function specialCountFunction(item, name) {
    return item[name].length;
}
```

So then you'd call it like this:

```
var name = "whatever_the_name_is";
var count = specialCountFunction(someitem, name);
```